# Can I use Eisenstein's criterion to show $x^{4}-2x^{3}+2x^{2}+x+4$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

> Can I use Eisenstein's criterion to show $x^{4}-2x^{3}+2x^{2}+x+4$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$?

Can I say that there does not exist a prime that divides both $2$ and $1$? Or is there another way to show it is reducible? Do I just use rational root test?

Comment: Eisenstein's criterion is for irreducibility, not reducibility.

Comment: And rational root test only gives you (or excludes the existence of) linear factors. This polynomial may be the product of two irreducible quadratic factors, and the rational root test doesn't say (as easily) anything about that.

Comment: See also: [Factoring/Reducing a polynomial $x^4 -2x^3 + 2x^2 + x + 4$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1535196)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check this yourself. The basic theorem is that, if this factors over the rationals, in fact it factors over the integers.

> The second result states that if a non-constant polynomial with
>   integer coefficients is irreducible over the integers, then it is also
>   irreducible if it is considered as a polynomial over the rationals.

[This is called Gauss's Lemma; one of them, anyway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%27s_lemma_(polynomial)). Writing as $(x^2 + ax + c)(x^2 + bx + d),$ we find $cd = 4,$ so we have some four possibilities to investigate:
$$  (x^2 + ax + 1)(x^2 + bx + 4),$$
 $$  (x^2 + ax + 2)(x^2 + bx + 2),$$
$$  (x^2 + ax - 1)(x^2 + bx - 4),$$
$$  (x^2 + ax - 2)(x^2 + bx -2),$$
where, in each one, we see if we can find integer values for $a,b$ that make the multiplication come out as your $x^4 - 2  x^3 + 2  x^2 + x + 4. $ It is pretty easy (in each of four) to find the coefficient of $x^3$ as a combination of $a,b,$ it is also easy to find the coefficient of $x.$ If any of the four gives integer values, the final thing is to see how the coefficient of $x^2$ comes out.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply and help me! I understand now and excuse me for my elementary knowledge on the subject!

Comment: @numericalorange please let me know when you finish it, and what you come to conclude about factoring.